# JOptionPane broken on Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, stream, joptionpane, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am a programming student in Spain, lately we've been learning about file input and output with objects, recently we've been developing a small program that asks for some data, writes it into a file and shows everything the file contains using `JOptionPane`.

My problem is that my `JOptionPane` seems to literally not work, program just stops there, doesn't throw any exception, doesn't follow up...

I've tried it in the computer of a friend and it works there, also asked my teacher but he is clueless, any ideas on what's going on?

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduce la matricula del vehículo");
        String matricula = pideInput();
        System.out.println("Introduce la marca del vehículo");
        String marca = pideInput();
        System.out.println("Introduce el tamaño del deposito del vehículo");
        Double tamDeposito = pideNum();
        System.out.println("Introduce el modelo del vehículo");
        String modelo = pideInput();
        try {
            MiObjectOutputStream escritor = new MiObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:\\vehiculos.dat",true));
            escritor.writeObject(new Vehiculo(matricula,marca,tamDeposito,modelo));
            escritor.close();
            escritor.flush();
            MiObjectInputStream lector = new MiObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\vehiculos.dat"));
            try{
            
                while(true){
                    Vehiculo v;
                    v = (Vehiculo) lector.readObject();
                    String desc = v.toString();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, desc);
                    System.out.println(desc);
                }   
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }catch (EOFException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            lector.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    private static double pideNum(){
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input = -1;
        try{
            input = lector.nextDouble();
        }catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error, se debe introducir un número adecuado");
            return pideNum();
        }
        return input;
    }
    
    private static String pideInput(){
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        return lector.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Vehicle class:

```
public class Vehiculo implements Serializable{
    String matricula;
    String marca;
    String modelo;
    double tamDeposito;
    public Vehiculo(String matricula, String marca, double tamDeposito, String modelo) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.tamDeposito = tamDeposito;
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehiculo{" + "matricula=" + matricula + ", marca=" + marca + ", modelo=" + modelo + ", tamDeposito=" + tamDeposito + '}';
    }
}
```

Custom stream:

```
public class MiObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
    public MiObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
    }
    public MiObjectOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader(){
        //Fumate un petardo
    } 
}
```

The custom `ObjectInputStream` is mostly the same as the output one, only differences are that it extends `ObjectInputStream`, uses `InputStream` as a param in the constructor and Overrides `readStreamHeader()` instead of `writeStreamHeader()`.

Edit: tried uninstalling, error popped up and cant uninstall, it seems some netbeans process is still open, nothing on task manager tho.

`running uninstallation logic NameResolver - to parse C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2 [2System.getProperty(netbeans.default_userdir_root): C:\Users\Alumno\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans System.getProperty(netbeans.default_userdir_root): C:\Users\Alumno\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans It appears that the following instance of the NetBeans IDE is still running: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2 A lock file exists at  C:\Users\Alumno\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\lock Please close this NetBeans IDE prior to continuing with uninstallation. show message dialog title: Critical Error message: It appears that the following instance of the NetBeans IDE is still running: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2 A lock file exists at  C:\Users\Alumno\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\lock Please close this NetBeans IDE prior to continuing with uninstallation.`

Comment: `while(true)` will keep the event dispatch thread busy and thus Swing cannot draw the option pane. If the program really stops you're probably getting some runtime exception. Any output on the command line?

Comment: is there a better way to loop throughout the file then? my intention is to keep showing JOptionPane until an EOF Exception pops up

Comment: According to the JavaDoc `showMessageDialog()` should create a modal dialog so it seems to be blocking. That means you should see the dialog somewhere on your screen (not necessarily where you expect it to be) and the program will wait for you to close it. Aside from that you need to break out of that loop - are you planning to use the `EOFException` for that?

Comment: No popups on my screen, I was planning to do that since i dont really know how else you can know where the file ends

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger or at least adding `System.out.println(...);` statements into your code to see where it seems to "stop"? If you put something before opening the dialog, do you see it at least once?

Comment: yeah, deleted the println before posting but anything before the JOptionPane prints once, anything after gets no output.

Comment: That sounds like either your application is still running and you're just not seeing the dialog or your system has some issues with the Java graphics setup (not sure what that could be though).